# Python Requests Strange URL %-Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, url-encoding, mojibake

Using Python 3.6.1, Requests 2.13.0, I am getting strange encoding of the URL being requested. I have a URL with Chinese characters in the query string, for example `huà 話 用`, which should %-encode to `hu%C3%A0%20%E8%A9%B1%20%E7%94%A8` or even `hu%C3%A0+%E8%A9%B1+%E7%94%A8`, but for some reason it is %-encoding to `hu%C3%83%C2%A0%20%C3%A8%C2%A9%C2%B1%20%C3%A7%C2%94%C2%A8`. This is not correct. I've been using http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ page to help me work the encodings. I've also used JavaScript `encodeURI` and PHP `urlencode` and don't get anything near what I see the Requests library doing.

Am I doing something wrong such that the encoding is so far off?

UPDATE:
I looked into Mojibake encoding and dug into the Requests library a little more and found out what the problem is, but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

I'm making a call against an internal server, using a simple `.get(url)` call. The call goes to the server and gets a redirect response. The redirect page has a `meta charset="UTF-8"` in the header and the URL listed in it is correct. The `location` header leaving the server is ok; it is encoded as UTF-8 and the `Content-Type` header has a `charset=UTF-8` on it. However, when I debug the redirect response in Python I note that the header on the response object is incorrect, it doesn't seem to be decoded correctly. The `headers` property contains this in `location`: `huÃ\xa0 è©± ç\x94`. As said above, it should be decoded as: `huà 話 用`. So, that strange URL query string get's % encoded by Requests and set back to the server, which then rejects that URL (obviously).

Is there something I can do to prevent Requests from messing this up? Or get it to correctly decode the `location` header? Web browsers don't seem to have trouble with this.

Comment: You'll have to show your code to see if you are doing anything wrong; I don't think `requests` would do this by itself normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) encoding. The bytes encoded are those of the Latin-1 interpretation of the UTF-8 bytes:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> text = 'huà 話 用'
>>> quote(text)
'hu%C3%A0%20%E8%A9%B1%20%E7%94%A8'
>>> quote(text.encode('utf8').decode('latin1'))
'hu%C3%83%C2%A0%20%C3%A8%C2%A9%C2%B1%20%C3%A7%C2%94%C2%A8'
```

You can reverse the process by manually encoding to Latin-1 again, then decoding from UTF-8:

```
>>> unquote('hu%C3%83%C2%A0%20%C3%A8%C2%A9%C2%B1%20%C3%A7%C2%94%C2%A8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'huà 話 用'
```

or you could use the [`ftfy` library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to automate fixing the wrong encoding (`ftfy` usually does a much better job, especially when Windows codepages are involved in the Mojibake):

```
>>> from ftfy import fix_text
>>> fix_text(unquote('hu%C3%83%C2%A0%20%C3%A8%C2%A9%C2%B1%20%C3%A7%C2%94%C2%A8'))
'huà 話 用'
```

You said this about the source of the URL:

> The location header leaving the server is ok; it is encoded as UTF-8

That's your problem, right there. HTTP headers are *always encoded as Latin-1*<sup>(*)</sup>. The server MUST set the Location header to a fully percent-encoded URL, so that all UTF-8 bytes are represented as `%HH` escape sequences. These are just ASCII characters, perfectly save in a Latin-1 context.

If your server sends the header as un-escaped UTF-8 bytes, then HTTP clients (including `requests`) will decode that as Latin-1 instead resulting in the exact Mojibake problem you observed. And because the URL contains invalid URL characters, `requests` escapes the Mojibake result to the percent-encoded version.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Actually, the `Location` header should be an [`absoluteURI`  as per RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3) which is always ASCII (7-bit) clean data, but because some other HTTP headers allow for 'descriptive' text, Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) is the accepted default encoding for header data. See the [`TEXT` rule in section 2.2 of the HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2), and the [`http.client` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) that ultimately decodes the headers for `requests` follows this RFC in this regard when decoding non-ASCII data in any header. You can provide non-Latin-1 data only if wrapped as per [the Message Header Extensions RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), but this doesn't apply to the `Location` header.

Comment: So how do I prevent `Request` from doing that. I'm working with all unicode strings in Python 3, so I wouldn't ever expect it would do this.

Comment: @cjbarth: again, I don't know how you are passing in URLs to requests. This is not anything that I'd expect `requests` for actually doing.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details about what is happening. Thanks for your comments about Mojibake encoding.

Comment: @cjbarth: I'm afraid that it is your server that is the issue here; I've added the relevant standards information to the post. Also see [What charset SHOULD be used for a Location: header in a 301 response?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7654207)